# Angular mat-checkbox getElementById

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I've got a problem with the mat-checkbox from angular material. I've given the checkbox an ID like this:

```
<mat-checkbox class="toolbar-checkbox" id="myCheckbox">
    MyCheckbox
</mat-checkbox>
```

After that I'm trying to something with this element like this:

```
(<MatCheckbox>document.getElementById('myCheckbox')).checked = true;
```

But unfortunally I'm getting this error:

```
TS2352: Type 'HTMLElement' cannot be converted to type 'MatCheckbox'. 
Property '_changeDetectorRef' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'. 
(<MatCheckbox>document.getElementById('asdasd')).checked = true;
```

How can I solve this, or is there a better way to do something with an checkbox without using [(ngModel)]?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [**ViewChild**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator. Change your template to this:

```
<mat-checkbox class="toolbar-checkbox" #myCheckbox>
    MyCheckbox
</mat-checkbox>
```

.. and in your typescript:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCheckbox } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
    ..... 
})
export class YourComponent {
    @ViewChild('myCheckbox') private myCheckbox: MatCheckbox;

    // You can then access properties of myCheckbox 
    // e.g. this.myCheckbox.checked
}
```

See this working [**StackBlitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-beta-12-fgibqb?file=app/app.component.ts).

Comment: What if my checkbox has a dynamic id?

Comment: @LetieTechera can you share a stackblitz example of how your component looks like?

Comment: I like this answer. But is there a way to get multiple MatCheckboxes by a class and set all there check states to true?  Or do you have to declare multiple ViewChild properties?

Comment: @Sam, yes you can using `ViewChildren`. Have a look at this article: https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
<mat-checkbox class="toolbar-checkbox" [checked] = "myCondition" id="myCheckbox">
    MyCheckbox
</mat-checkbox>
```

where myCondition is set in the template or the class and could be any logical expression.

or

```
<mat-checkbox class="toolbar-checkbox" id="myCheckbox" [checked] = "myCondition()">
    MyCheckbox
</mat-checkbox>
```

where myCondition() is a method defined in the class and should return a boolean value, based on any logical expression.

This would allow you skip any DOM manipulation and take care of the checkbox checked status in the template.

Comment: Not a good solution. This will cause a neverending call of the function, causing slowness and bad performance. (Try console logging something inside the function and you'll see).

Answer (score 0):

Digging through what `mat-checkbox` generate in html i found that `mat-checkbox` create a hidden html `input type="checkbox"` so you can get the checked value by adding **"-input"** in the id in the `getElementById` call,  for example if your `mat-checkbox` id is `myinputid`:

```
const getmyinput: boolean = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('myinputid-input')).checked;
```

It solve the problem for **dynamic id**, example adding string `i` in the middle:

```
const getmyinput: boolean = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('myinputid' + String(i) + '-input')).checked;
```